# Is there a reconstruction of the Proto-Sinaitic alphabet that's consistent with meaningful translations of all known Proto-Sinaitic inscriptions?

Tags: alphabets

Including those from Wadi el-Ḥol, Serabit el-Khadim, Lahun, and Bir en-Naṣb. I know that we can't yet prove that any reconstruction is accurate, but is there one that is at least consistent with meaningful translations of all of these inscriptions? If this isn't the place to ask this, where is?

Comment: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/28832/nathan-tracey https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/28842/nathan-tracey Why are you creating a new account for each question?

Comment: I didn't know that I was!

Comment: There's a procedure to merge the accounts, though I'm not sure how exactly that works. A moderator can be more help.

Comment: Make sure that you fully register on the site so that your past questions can be tracked properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will we ever decipher the Wadi el-Ḥol and Serabit el-Khadim inscriptions?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/36344/will-we-ever-decipher-the-wadi-el-%e1%b8%a4ol-and-serabit-el-khadim-inscriptions)

Comment: @NathanTracey In order to have your accounts merged, please file a request in the [**Contact**](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/contact) page. Write a short description of what happened but you can also add the links to the other accounts, so it's easier to deal with.